# Eclipse IDE setup for multi-language development

Tags: java, python, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for Java EE and Python development.

Right now I have two different Eclipse instance, one setup for Java EE development (with related plugins installed) and another for Python development (with related plugins installed)

Is this a good approach or should I have single Eclipse instance with all plugins installed? Whether there would be any performance issue when I install all plugins?

Please let me know what is the recommended practice?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is **pure** style and personal choice. But I think there are certain aspects that one should consider when making that decision for himself:

1. Is CPU / memory a problem for you - when you have 16 or 32 GB of RAM in your machine, it doesn't matter if one eclipse is running or 5. But there are still people around that go with much less than that.
2. In my personal experience, the more plugins you have, the more time is required when going for a fresh install (and I personally found moving workspaces from one eclipse version to another major eclipse version to be painful sometimes, so I prefer doing fresh installations). In other words: how much flexibility do you need?
3. Does it improve your workflow when everything is within **one** eclipse session? Or is the other way round, and sometimes it is helpful that you can shutdown, restart, upgrade, ... your Java eclipse without affecting your python work?

And my personal hint: I actually did not like the python things within eclipse. Thus I switched to [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for all my python work. Yes that means that I have to know to use two different tools, but I found that using the free community edition of pycharm actually to be a great thing. Maybe that policy from JetBrains can also guide you: those people put out *language* specific IDEs all the time - instead of providing that **one** IDE that works for everything and everybody.